# Symfony Filter not working

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, yaml

My schema:

```
Poster:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
    Sluggable:
      fields:[name]
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    filename:
      type: string(255)
      notnull: true
    approved:
      type: boolean(1)
      default: false
    start_date:
      type: date
      notnull: true
    end_date:
      type: date    
      notnull: true  
    user_id:
      type: integer(20)
      default: 1
  attributes:
    export: all
    validate: true
  relations:
    User:
      class: sfGuardUser
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignType: many
      foreignAlias: Posters
```

I have a module `poster` generated by `doctrine:generate-admin`. In the list view, I see the filters for all the fields including `start_date` and `end_date`. Now, the problem is, that these two filters are not working as they should. e.g. I provided a range for `Start Date` and pressed `filter`, in the response page, I saw the `SQL queries` tab of the web debug toolbar but there I don't see any indication for constraining the query according to the provided constraint. I just see this:

```
SET NAMES 'UTF8'
0.00s, "doctrine" connection

SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results FROM poster p
0.00s, "doctrine" connection

SELECT s.id AS s__id, s.first_name AS s__first_name, s.last_name AS s__last_name, s.email_address AS s__email_address, s.username AS s__username, s.algorithm AS s__algorithm, s.salt AS s__salt, s.password AS s__password, s.is_active AS s__is_active, s.is_super_admin AS s__is_super_admin, s.last_login AS s__last_login, s.created_at AS s__created_at, s.updated_at AS s__updated_at FROM sf_guard_user s
0.00s, "doctrine" connection

SELECT p.id AS p__id, p.name AS p__name, p.enabled AS p__enabled, p.layout AS p__layout, p.created_at AS p__created_at, p.updated_at AS p__updated_at, p.slug AS p__slug FROM place p
0.00s, "doctrine" connection

SELECT p.id AS p__id, p.name AS p__name, p.filename AS p__filename, p.approved AS p__approved, p.start_date AS p__start_date, p.end_date AS p__end_date, p.user_id AS p__user_id, p.created_at AS p__created_at, p.updated_at AS p__updated_at, p.slug AS p__slug FROM poster p LIMIT 10
0.00s, "doctrine" connection

SELECT s.id AS s__id, s.first_name AS s__first_name, s.last_name AS s__last_name, s.email_address AS s__email_address, s.username AS s__username, s.algorithm AS s__algorithm, s.salt AS s__salt, s.password AS s__password, s.is_active AS s__is_active, s.is_super_admin AS s__is_super_admin, s.last_login AS s__last_login, s.created_at AS s__created_at, s.updated_at AS s__updated_at FROM sf_guard_user s WHERE (s.id = '2') LIMIT 1
```

Now, as the `Poster` model is Timestampable, there is a `created_at` field. I tried to filter the results by giving a range to this field, and in the queries tab, I now see

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results FROM poster p WHERE p.created_at >= '2011-12-15 00:00:00' AND p.created_at <= '2011-12-24 23:59:59'
```

Is that a bug in symfony? Please help.

**UPDATE**: Ok, I did a little investigation and found that there is no corresponding `addFieldNameColumnQuery` function in `BasePosterFilter.class.php`. So again, is that default symfony behaviour or is that some bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony doesn't create any `addFieldNameColumnQuery` for `Doctrine` (or `addFieldNameColumnCriteria` for `Propel`), but simply fields are "mapped" trough own types (Number, Text, Boolean, Date, ForeignKey), as you see in `getFields()` of a `BaseMyModelFormFilter` class, assigning the right filter when an input filter is used.

Instead if you add a new field, say `myfield`, you have to create a function `addMyfieldNameColumnQuery` (or `addMyfieldNameColumnCriteria`) to allows Symfony to get and add the right sql filter.

Comment: Well, I have a field which is a `ForeignKey` but I'd like it to behave like `Text`. I changed `getFields` and corresponding widget/validatorSchemas. now according to [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfFormFilterDoctrine) and its source, `addTextQuery` should be called, which should add a `%LIKE%` query. What's actually  happening is either no query is added or a `=` query is added. Why is that happening?

Comment: I tried to help you about answering to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503938/symfony-filter-change-behaviour-from-field-value-to-field-like-value/8504873