# symfony filter change behaviour from [field=value] to [field LIKE %value%]

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-forms

In my filter, a field's behaviour is to search in the DB table for a row that has the value of the field `equal` to the value provided in filtering form. I'd like to change its behavior to search in DB table for a row/rows that have field value matching to that provided in the form(`%LIKE%`).

I know it can be done by adding a `addFieldnameColumnQuery` method to the filter class but What I want to know is, is there another way?

The field happens to be a foreign key and I want it to work like a normal text field.

**UPDATE**: this was a silly mistake. I needed to assign a sfWidgetFormFilterInput to the widgetSchema but I was using sfWidgetFormInput which was causing it to look for equality instead of matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never hear about another way... have a look at `sfFormFilterDoctrine` class located in `lib\vendor\symfony\lib\plugins\sfDoctrinePlugin\lib\form` to understand how this system works and how you can write your `addFieldnameColumnQuery`

**UPDATE**
To change just the filter behaviour for a field, say `myfield`, from *foreign key* to normal *text* you can simply set the widget  and override `getFields()` in `MymoduleFormFilter` class with some code like this:

```
  public function configure()
  {
      $this->setWidget('myfield', new sfWidgetFormFilterInput());
      $this->setValidator('myfield', new sfValidatorPass(array('required' => false)));
  }

  public function getFields()
  {
      $fields = parent::getFields();
      $fields['myfield'] = 'Text';
      return $fields;
  }
```

Instead if you define a field to search in a joined table you have yet to set the widget according to the field name you wrote in generator.yml

```
filter:
   display: [... some fields ..., myfield]
```

and finally add `addMyfieldColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $values)` with inside the *join* and *where* code. Sorry, no snippet for this because I use Propel.

Comment: Well, that was what I already went for, my point was, in this way, we have to write 3 lines of code, maybe instead, we can change generator.yml at just one place.