# Symfony 1.4: Creating custom filters. Foreign keys and repeated keys with different filters (propel)

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel

I have a table, **TableModule**, with 2 foreign keys, let's say **fk1** and **fk2**.

- **fk1** goes to **pk1** in table **Table 1**
- **fk2** goes to **pk2** in table **Table 2**

I created a module. let's say, **Module**, which uses the **TableModule** (the one with the **fk's**)

I want to create 4 filters for those **fk**: 2 input text and 2 dropdowns. In particular, I want to create **two** filters **per fk**. This is:

```
For fk1 I would get:
  -InputText
  -Dropdown (choice in propel) 
For fk2 I would get:
  -InputText
  -Dropdown (choice in propel)
```

Of course, this would show the results of **Table1** and **Table2**.

Now, in my **config.yml** I got:

```
    ...
    filter:
      display: [fk1, fk1TextFilter, fk2, fk2TextFilter]
    ...
```

This is: **fk1** and **fk2** would be filtered as dropdowns, The *partials* **fk1TextFilter** and **fk2TextFilter** must be customized for filtering using a text input.

Why I created those *partials*? Because **I can't duplicate the fk in the config.yml!!**

In `lib/filter/table1/ModuleFormFilter` I did  (notice that is in **table1**):

```
 public function configure()
 {
  $this->setWidgets(array(
  'fk1'                => new sfWidgetFormPropelChoice(array('model' => 'table1',  'add_empty' => true,)),
  'fk1TextFilter'      => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
  'fk2'                => new sfWidgetFormPropelChoice(array('model' => 'table2',  'add_empty' => true,)),
  'fk2TextFilter'      => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
  ));

$this->setValidators(array(
  'fk1TextFilter'      => new sfValidatorPropelChoice(array('model' => 'table1', 'column' => 'id', 'required' => false)),
  'fk1'                => new sfValidatorPropelChoice(array('model' => 'table1', 'column' => 'id', 'required' => false)),
  'fk2TextFilter'      => new sfValidatorPropelChoice(array('model' => 'table2', 'column' => 'id', 'required' => false)),
  'fk2'                => new sfValidatorPropelChoice(array('model' => 'table2', 'column' => 'id', 'required' => false)),
));

$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
  new sfValidatorPropelUnique(array('model' => 'table2', 'column' => array('fk2')))
);

$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('model[%s]');

$this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);
```

}

This is: created 2 textInput and 2 dropdowns as stated earlier.

If I use -could be the inputtext or the dropdowns- just the **fk** this will work OK. the problem is that **I can't duplicate the fk's**. I can't do:

```
  $this->setWidgets(array(
  'fk1'   => new sfWidgetFormPropelChoice(array('model' => 'table1',  'add_empty' => true,)),
  'fk1'   => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
  'fk2'   => new sfWidgetFormPropelChoice(array('model' => 'table2',  'add_empty' => true,)),
  'fk2'   => new sfWidgetFormInput(),
  ));
```

If I run the page I get:

```
You must define a "filterByfk1TextFilter" method in the ModelQuery class to be able to filter with the "fk1TextFilter" field.
```

I found some links ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461703/symfony-admin-filter-with-join), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502824/symfony-filter-not-working)) but is not working for me. I don't have in the symfony docs concrete examples.

**What I must created and how?**

By now I have, in the same `lib/filter/table1/ModuleFormFilter`:

```
 public function getFields()
 {
  $fields = parent::getFields();
  $fields['fk1TextFilter'] = 'fk1TextFilter';
  $fields['fk2TextFilter'] = 'fk2TextFilter';
  return $fields;
 }

public function addModelfk1TextFilterQuery($query, $field, $value)
{
 //add your filter query!
 //for example in your case
 $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
 $query =  ModelQuery::create()
  ->filterByfk1TextFilter()
  ->find();

 //remember to return the $query!
 return $query;
}
```

Is not working for me. Could you help me please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Black Magic:

There are many different ways. None worked for me, at least those in the links I posted.

Nevertheless, using: **add[VirtualColumnName]ColumnCriteria** allows you to customize filters.

In this case, after all the code I wrote (and changing **addModelfk1TextFilterQuery()**) just add:

```
public function addfk1TextFilterColumnCriteria($query, $field, $value)
{
  //Here just put a query in propel, for ex:

  $query = $query->useTableModel()
                 ->filterByName("*$value*")
               ->endUse()
               ->find();
 return $query;
}
```

Hoping that this will help some others!

**Mini Edit**: do some **echoes** to `$field` and `$values` for clarification

Answer (score 4):

For those of you using Doctrine, this is a simple extension on my 'User Profile' model to allow filtering by fields on the sfGuardUser model from sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.

My 'profile' class was called Member, and referenced sfGuardUser via a User relation via a user_id column.

Hope someone finds it useful!

```
class MemberFormFilter extends BaseMemberFormFilter {

  public function configure() {
    $this->setWidget('first_name', new sfWidgetFormInputText());
    $this->setWidget('last_name', new sfWidgetFormInputText());
    $this->setWidget('email_address', new sfWidgetFormInputText());

    $this->setValidator('first_name', new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false)));
    $this->setValidator('last_name', new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false)));
    $this->setValidator('email_address', new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false)));
  }

  public function getFields() {
    return array_merge(parent::getFields(), array(
      'first_name' => 'Text',
      'last_name' => 'Text',
      'email_address' => 'Text'
    ));
  }

  public function addFirstNameColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $value) {
    $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
    return $query->leftJoin($rootAlias.'.User u')
      ->where('u.first_name LIKE ?', "%$value%");
  }

  public function addLastNameColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $value) {
    $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
    return $query->leftJoin($rootAlias.'.User u')
      ->where('u.last_name LIKE ?', "%$value%");
  }

  public function addEmailAddressColumnQuery(Doctrine_Query $query, $field, $value) {
    $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();
    return $query->leftJoin($rootAlias.'.User u')
      ->where('u.email_address LIKE ?', "%$value%");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better putting **addWhere** instead of **where** on each of the "addXColumnQuery functions, because this way will preserve and combine the other filters set.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.